# Push not called in minimize State

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, background

When Application is in minimize state,

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

above method not getting called. I am receiving the push but this method is not getting called. I want to update the UI as soon as I receive the push and app is in background state.

Payload of Notification:

```
{    "access_token" = 123;    aps =     {        alert =         {            body = "Your dispute has been resolved.";            title = "Dispute Resolved.";        };        badge = 0;        "content-available" = 1;        sound = default;    };    "content_available" = true;    "fixed_price" = "";    "gcm.message_id" = 123232;    "gcm.notification.fixed_price" = "";    "gcm.notification.job_id" = 111;    "gcm.notification.request_id" = 0;    "gcm.notification.type" = 116;    "google.c.a.e" = 1;    "google.c.sender.id" = 13113;    "job_id" = 111;    message = "Your dispute has been resolved.";    "push_type" = 116;    "request_id" = 0;    title = "Dispute Resolved.";    "user_id" = 111;    username = "Dispute Resolved.";}
```

**XCode: 11.3
Device: iPhone XR
OS: 13.3.1**

*Background Modes are also Enabled.*

[image]

Comment: maybe that makes sense -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40475993/7512091

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I have clearly mentioned the method name which needs to be called in background state. I do not want to click on the notification.

Comment: Honest opinion, you don't have to update UI while your app is in background state, its pointless. It's better you do it when the app comes foreground.

Comment: Dear @shinoy:
To update UI means I have to call some methods when app comes to foreground as soon as I get to know that something is triggered from the backend side. To do this, when app is in background state and some notification arrives, the app must call the above mentioned method. But in my case, it is not happening :(